# Using fields from main table in LEFT JOIN Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select values by a helping calender tables. The query looks like:

```
SELECT
    t1.starttime,
    t1.endtime,
    t2.sum_val1,
    t2.avg_val2
FROM
    eco_546d9dff955b5_help t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        SUM(val1) AS sum_val1,
        AVG(val2) AS avg_val2
    FROM
        eco_546d9dff955b5
    WHERE
        `timestamp` > t1.starttime
    AND `timestamp` <= t1.endtime
) t2 ON t1.starttime <= t2.`timestamp` AND t1.endtime >= t2.`timestamp`
```

But on running this code i get "Unkown column t1.starttime in where-clause"? Is it possible to make t1.starttime available for subquery?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and corresponding desired result

Comment: What exactly do you want to get?

Comment: As long as LEFT JOIN is used, you could remove the WHERE clause from inner selection. Result will be same. I would suggest so, if there table "eco_546d9dff955b5" doesn't contain millions of records, to not  to get performance issues.